# Control MapKit pin annotation tap selection

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, segue

I'm trying to capture MapKit pin tap  selection selection to perform segue to the detail view for this location, I have a property in the annotation pin for that:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface alrededorLocation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *_name;
    NSString *_address;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
    NSDictionary *additionalInfo;
}
```

But I'm not able to capture the pin selection to perform the segue, I tried controlling it in `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view`

But I wasn't successful to get the selected pin reference.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you set up the delegate properly on your mapView?

Comment: Yes, I did. the problem is how to get the selected pin. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, that. Have you tried accessing the view.annotation property in that method?

Comment: alrededorLocation *tempLocation = view.annotation;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detalle" sender:tempLocation];
Here it is. the problem is that I realize I need to control annotation View instead of annotation, with this code the segue is perfumed when clicking the pin. Many thanks

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I helped.  I'll compose an answer so you can mark the question answered down below.

Btw, don't forget to name your classes with starting capital letters - AlderorLocation. And the casting is a good practice too to avoid the warnings.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to control the tap in the annotation view instead on the annotation?

Comment: Yes, you should add an accessory view to your annotation view, and then place your code in the `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method.

[Here's the official documentation from Apple.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this question, the answer is to access the `annotation` property of `MKAnnotationView`. For this specific case, the code that worked is:

```
AlrededorLocation *tempLocation = (AlderorLocation *)view.annotation;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detalle" sender:tempLocation];
```